# self-extractor that will extract and run a file

Tags: .net, exe, self-extracting

i have two files, an EXE an DLL

the exe is a build of a vb.net application and i need the DLL in there too

what i want is a self extractor that will put these files together, then when run it will extract them and immeidately run the EXE

is there a VERY SIMPLE and EASY TO USE OUT OF THE BOX software that will do this? commercial or not, it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagese.htm).

Answer (score 11):

You can use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (free and open-source). It's very flexible, yet it can be used for such simple tasks, too (and it has served me well in such cases). Assuming your files are named `yourapp.exe` and `yourlib.dll`, you could use this script:

```
# this will be the created executable archive
OutFile "archive.exe"
# define the directory to install to, the installer's directory in this case 
InstallDir $EXEDIR

# don't create a window for the unarchiver
# You could get fancy and do all kinds of configuration 
#   in the non-silent install; this example is the simplest it can be.
SilentInstall silent

# the executable part
Section

# define the output path for the following files
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
# define what to install and place it in the output path...
# ...your app...
File yourapp.exe
# ...and the library.
File yourlib.dll

# run your application
ExecShell yourapp.exe

# done
SectionEnd
```

Install NSIS, create this script as `archive.nsi`, right click it and select "Compile with NSIS". The file `archive.exe` will be created.

Then, on the target system, all the user needs to do is launch `archive.exe`; the script will unpack and run your program.

(If you want to get fancy, you can look into the tutorials that are installed with NSIS, or [see this page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials).)